# How I can change the border-color of multiple buttons in a form with only one attribute?

Tags: html, css

I wonder how I can change the border-color of multiple buttons in a form with only one attribute, I mean like this:

Instead of:

```
<form name="form">
    <input type="button" name="button1" value="1" style="border-color: red">
    <input type="button" name="button2" value="2" style="border-color: red">
    <input type="button" name="button3" value="3" style="border-color: red">
</form>
```

I want something like:

```
<form name="form" style="border-color: red">
    <input type="button" name="button1" value="1">
    <input type="button" name="button2" value="2">
    <input type="button" name="button3" value="3">
</form>
```

Comment: Shhh... The toolbar at the top of the textfield in which you typed this has a link to the help...

Answer (score 5):

one way is to use a css selector

```
form input[type=button]
{
    border-color: red;
}
```

you can use an ID too:

```
#myForm input[type=button]
{
    border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML :

```
<form class=red> ...
```

CSS :

```
form.red input[type=button] {
   border-color:red;
}
```

Comment: So, it will change all the buttons borders to RED in the form?

Comment: @12345 I thought this was the goal.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes here. Can you point my error, please ?

Comment: I don't see how this answer has less votes than Andrew's, despite being older and having roughly the same answer.